# NativeScript: Whenever I add a local plugin that I built in native script project and then run it in android there exception occurs

Tags: android, plugins, nativescript, version

When I build native script project and run the project on android then there is no issue. But when I add my local plugin then following issue occurs:

```
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
  System.err: Calling js method onViewAttachedToWindow failed
  System.err: Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle$State.isAtLeast, parameter state
  System.err:
  System.err: StackTrace:
  System.err: _onAttachedToWindow(file: app/webpack:/demo/node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/frame/index.android.js:118:0)
  System.err:   at onViewAttachedToWindow(file: app/webpack:/demo/node_modules/@nativescript/core/ui/frame/index.android.js:46:0)
  System.err:   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
  System.err:   at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1302)
  System.err:   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1188)
  System.err:   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1175)
  System.err:   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1153)
  System.err:   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1149)
  System.err:   at com.tns.gen.java.lang.Object_vendor_24835_49_.onViewAttachedToWindow(Object_vendor_24835_49_.java:20)
  System.err:   at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:21301)
  System.err:   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3491)
  System.err:   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3498)
  System.err:   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3498)
  System.err:   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3498)
  System.err:   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3498)
  System.err:   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3498)
  System.err:   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2820)
  System.err:   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2328)
  System.err:   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9087)
  System.err:   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1231)
  System.err:   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1239)
  System.err:   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:899)
  System.err:   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:832)
  System.err:   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1214)
  System.err:   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
  System.err:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  System.err:   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
  System.err:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
  System.err:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
  System.err:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  System.err:   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
  System.err:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

When I add my local plugin using

```
   ns add plugin 'path'
```

and run then the project asks for version update from minSdk 17 to minSdk to 21. Then The above mentioned Error occurs.

Without adding plugin even if I update version It works.

I tried by updating all the plugins in package.json and also I tried to remove  node_modules and platform and re-add them.

But also the issue is still occurring.

Hoping for the solution to the problem As I am new to nativescript and I am lost.